# Send navigation bar to back and my sidemenu to front

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am currently using this [sidebar](https://github.com/edekhayser/FrostedSidebar) as a side menu to my app and it's working great. However, whenever I embed a tab item in a navigation controller, and I tap the burger icon, the side menu isn't displayed properly: the navigation bar is in front of the side menu, making the side menu looked cut.

I've tried using this code, but it throws an issue

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

How do I effectively send my navigation bar to be always behind my other subviews (e.g. my side menu)? Or is there another way to fix this? Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the navigation bar will always be in the front by default; I solved this by setting the navigation bar to translucent:

```
    func setNavBarTranslucent(){
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 0.1
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = false
}
```